# PHP - Working with arrays from Graph API

Tags: php, arrays, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to retrieve certain values from the logged in Facebook user's profile, but I don't understand how to work with the arrays of data of varying size and display them in a readable format.
When I use:

```
echo 'education: ' . $user['education'] . "<br>";
```

I get something like this displayed on my page:

```
education: [{"concentration":[{"id":"150910074965217","name":"\u041f\u0440\u043e\u0433\u0440\u0430\u043c\u043d\u0430 \u0456\u043d\u0436\u0435\u043d\u0435\u0440\u0456\u044f"}],"school":{"id":"432852973511164","name":"\u041d\u0430\u0446\u0456\u043e\u043d\u0430\u043b\u044c\u043d\u0438\u0439 \u0443\u043d\u0456\u0432\u0435\u0440\u0441\u0438\u0442\u0435\u0442 \"\u041a\u0438\u0454\u0432\u043e-\u041c\u043e\u0433\u0438\u043b\u044f\u043d\u0441\u044c\u043a\u0430 \u0430\u043a\u0430\u0434\u0435\u043c\u0456\u044f\""},"type":"College","year":{"id":"185588044800194","name":"2017"},"id":"542291889188274"}]
```

It looks somewhat better when I test the same request in Graph API Explorer, as I actually get some real names there:

```
{
  "education": [
    {
      "concentration": [
        {
          "id": "150910074965217",
          "name": "Software engineering"
        }
      ],
      "school": {
        "id": "432852973511164",
        "name": "NaUKMA"
      },
      "type": "College",
      "year": {
        "id": "185588044800194",
        "name": "2017"
      },
      "id": "542291889188274"
    }
  ],
  "id": "1267239220026867"
}
```

The output looks much worse when I try to retrieve an array with multiple arguments (for example, for the user's `languages`)...

I'd like to retrieve only certain parts of the array (like the name of the school, its type and the year), taking into account that there might be several colleges the user studied in. How do I do it?

### UPDATE

```
$educationArray = json_decode($user['education']);

var_dump($educationArray);
```

gave me this:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[21]
      public 'concentration' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[20]
              ...
      public 'school' => 
        object(stdClass)[19]
          public 'id' => string '432852973511164' (length=15)
          public 'name' => string 'NaUKMA' (length=_another_number_here_)
      public 'type' => string 'College' (length=7)
      public 'year' => 
        object(stdClass)[18]
          public 'id' => string '185588044800194' (length=15)
          public 'name' => string '2017' (length=4)
      public 'id' => string '542291889188274' (length=15)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Facebook Graph API is returning a JSON Array Response. To parse the JSON Array into a PHP Array you can use:

```
$educationArray = json_decode($user['education']);
```

Then you can access the values in the array like this:

```
echo $educationArray->education[0]->school->id;
```

As for your question about only returning certain values, after taking a quick look at the Graph API it doesn't look like you can specify what parts of their Education history you want so its best just to return all of it and filter what you want out of it in PHP.

Comment: Tried this one, got 
**Notice: Undefined index: school**
when trying to `echo` ...

Comment: Still not working... **Notice: Trying to get property of non-object** ...but I added `var_dump($educationArray);` output to the main post. Maybe it'll be useful.